# I want to change container color but it doesn't work?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-bottomnavigation

when i press the bottomnavigationbar item why it doesnt work

Here the codes;

```
    Color? color;
  colorChange() {
    if (_pageIndex == 0) {
      color = AppColors.buttonColor;
    }
    if (_pageIndex == 1) {
      color = AppColors.buttonColor;
    }
    if (_pageIndex == 2) {
      color = AppColors.buttonColor;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

BottomNavBar item section,

```
items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Padding(
                  padding: context.paddingTop / 8,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: colorChange(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    width: 40,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.home_outlined,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                label: ''),
```

Comment: Can you include full widget,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method isn't returning any color but retuns a null at the end.

Try this:

```dart
Color? color;
  Color colorChange(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == _pageIndex) 
   {
      color = AppColors.buttonColor;
    }
    else{
      color = Colors.transparent;
    }
    return color;
  }
```

And in bottom Navigation bar item:

```dart
items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Padding(
                  padding: context.paddingTop / 8,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: colorChange(0),//here pass the index
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    width: 40,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.home_outlined,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                label: ''),
```

Comment: thank but, else if (_pageIndex == 1){}  while pageIndex 0 too change color why ?

Comment: Edited my answer. The color is assigned to all children so it will get the same color. So you have to pass the indexof each item. Check with current page. If its same send a color. If not return transparent. Edited my answer

Comment: Glad it did. Please accept the answer if it was helpful